# Reference for the Yajur Vedic verse to summon an army

Tags: vedas, identification-request, yajur-veda

I came across the following verse which was claimed to be from Yajur Veda which I'm unable to transliterate or find reference for. The Verse is for summoning an Army. The following pronunciation might be incorrect.

> Abbārtha Sura Rakshasī Vedi Sada

https://youtu.be/-aSbqiC6Sio?t=938

Any help with identifying the meaning and reference for this verse is appreciated!

Comment: I think it may just be a meaningless utterance the creators of the TV show made up.  In any case, as far as I know the Yajur Veda doesn't contain any mantras to magically summon an army.  That sounds like something that would be in the Atharvana Veda.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that it looks out of place in Yajur Vedas. I'm not able to say, but are you sure that the arrangement of words in this verse is hokum? It might have been picked up from Atharvana Veda and wrongly attributed to Yajur Veda.

Comment: Agree with Keshav's comment. Atharva Veda has mantras for victory, against one's enemies, success, but not specifically to raise an army. Be careful. Don't utter mantras that you don't completely understand what they do and you have not been schooled by a completely competent priest or holy man on how to pronounce. They can have the opposite effect if not pronounced EXACTLY correct!

Comment: Agreed. In this case I just wanted to verify the authenticity of the verse. I would be surprised if it turns out that the makers of the TV show took their creative license a bit too far to fabricate a verse and wrongly associate it with the Vedas. Spinning imaginary stories around mythology is one thing, but tampering with the Vedas is crossing the line.